# How to upgrade tomcat

Tags: tomcat, upgrade

can somebody tell, how to upgrade tomcat to the newest version? I have read from the tomcat webpage about upgrade but cant understand anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way:

- download new tomcat
- unpack it (somehwere else than current tomcat, you can have more than one at the same time
- start it (if you are already running tomcat, than you need to change the ports on which the new one works, go to etc/servlet.xml and change each port (typically there are 3 ports, on the very beginig for shutting down, and then in the middle for the http connection and ajp connector))
- deploy your webapp
- if it wasn't depended on context parameters (DM connection pools, JNDI ...) it may already work correctly
- if not add missing resources to etc/servlet.xml (check your existing tomcat installation what was defined under global resources). Make sure you are using the right parameters name, for example DBConnection pool has some new names)
- check if webapp works
- change your apache/network conf to point to new tomcat

If you were not using ugly hacks it is usually as simple as that.
Beware Tomcat 8.0.17 had bug and it did not render jsp properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no upgrade mechanism. So you have to read carefully migration guide if you are going to upgrade to major release, set up new instance of tomcat with corrected server.xml and other configs, deploy and test your apps with new tomcat. And finally point you proxy to new instance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in upgrade. Here's how I handle it.

1. Use the `CATALINA_BASE` and `CATALINA_HOME` settings. In particular, you want to set up a `CATALINA_BASE` that will contain all your configuration and web apps. You can also set in your `server.xml` a `docBase` or `xmlBase` setting to have an additional location where your web applications will live.
2. Use the following script to automatically download and unpack the latest Tomcat binary. This one is designed for the 10.1.x series. You can modify as needed for other series. This basically greps through the HTML, which isn't beautiful, but it does work.
3. This unpacks it and uses a symbolic link. If you prefer you could change it to not use a symbolic link, if you don't want to retain the older versions.

   #!/bin/bash

   echo "UPGRADING TO THE LATEST VERSION OF TOMCAT 10"

   # get the download link
   # grep -e allows a pattern to start with a dash

   TOMCAT_URL=$(curl -sS https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi | 
   grep -e "-10.1" | 
   grep '>tar.gz' | head -1 | grep -E -o 'https://[a-z0-9./-]+.tar.gz')

   echo Downloading from $TOMCAT_URL
   TOMCAT_NAME=$(echo $TOMCAT_URL | grep -E -o 'apache-tomcat-[0-9.]+[0-9]')
   echo Tomcat name: $TOMCAT_NAME

   DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
   cd $DIR || die "Couldn't cd to $DIR"

   rm -rf apache-tomcat $TOMCAT_NAME
   curl -sS $TOMCAT_URL | tar xfz -

   # edit this line for the correct user / group as needed
   chown -R tomcatuser:tomcatgroup $TOMCAT_NAME
   ln -s $TOMCAT_NAME apache-tomcat
   echo Completed upgrade to: $TOMCAT_NAME

This script above is a starting point. You should edit it as needed. If you're going to use this for automated, unattended upgrades, good to check return values for things like `curl` so it stops if the download fails, etc.

Sorry for the poor formatting. StackOverflow didn't let me correctly format Bash script code.